# For Statement in a Variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= va; i++) {
    var "v" + i + "x" = document.getElementById("v" + i + "x");
    var "v" + i + "y" = document.getElementById("v" + i + "y");
    var "v" + i + "r" = document.getElementById("v" + i + "r");
}
```

But i dont know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Add more code that you're willing to do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Dynamic variable names? Stop what ever you're doing, and use an array instead.

Comment: Yes Teeemu im trying to auto generate variables

Comment: Oh my God Thank you Teemu thats just what i need... kinda Can you put it in an Awnser because do i have to do this 40 times because va = 40?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic variables are not generally a good practice. You should avoid them. A better solution would be creating an object that would contain them like so:

```
var obj = {}; 

for (var i = 1; i <= va; i++) {

    obj["v" + i + "x"] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "x");
    obj["v" + i + "y"] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "y");
    obj["v" + i + "r"] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "r");

}
```

Later, you can access the elements like:

```
console.log( obj["v1r"] ); // Node with id v1r reference
console.log( obj["v5x"] ); // Node with id v5x reference
```

Comment: How exactly can i use the object, like if i want to do an alert do i write alert(v1x); and alert(v25x); ? Because in your Awnser with the console log it outputs: "<input placeholder="Vogel 1 Richtung" id="v1r" type="text">" And thats my input not the variable..... Oh i just realised that i forgot the .value at the end -_- Im sorry

Comment: @OfficielFreaks, the console log example outputs the reference to that element in the DOM. To check the value of that input do this: `alert( obj["v1r"].value )`

Comment: nvm found it out

Comment: @OfficielFreaks, use `value` property. My mistake, sorry, `val()` function is a jQuery method :)

Comment: i put v2r in there and now it says: "obj.v2r is undefined"

Comment: @OfficielFreaks, I gave you a general solution to your problem. If you have something more specific, please create a fiddle. I can't tell what how you're using the code and what HTML structure you have. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd better use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var elements = []; // init to an empty array
for (var i = 1; i <= va; i++) {
    elements[i] = []; // each array entry is itself an array
    elements[i]['x'] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "x");
    elements[i]['y'] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "y");
    elements[i]['r'] = document.getElementById("v" + i + "r");
}
```

Then use the appropriate indexes to retrieve your values:

```
console.log(elements[1]['x']);
```